# Android Developer: change version

Tags: android

Is there a way to change the Android version on my app without redoing everything? I just realized that Nook Color only has version 1.4. Well, I have my app set at 3.2 ... so those who have the Nook Color will not be able to access it. Why on earth did I do this to myself!

I am using Eclipse.

Comment: There is no Android 1.4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can certainly create multiple .apk files for different versions. See [this article about it](http://developer.android.com/training/multiple-apks/api.html). However, you may not need to if you haven't used any 3.2 API calls. You may be able to just change the minimum sdk level in the manifest file, update the version code, and republish your app.

Comment: cool beans. I am not sure if I used any 3.2API calls...but I used that because that is what my device uses.

Comment: @Cady - According to the [B&N developer web site](https://nookdeveloper.barnesandnoble.com/), the Nook color runs Android 2.2 (SDK level 8). The Nook Tablet runs 2.3 (SDK level 9). Set your project's build target to SDK level 8 and anywhere that you access API calls from later versions should light up as errors in your project.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to redo everything , but you can't use 3.2 API on nook color.  You'll have to lower your minSDK version in your AndroidManifest.xml to the nook and test your application.  If it doesn't compile you can look at using the compatibility libraries allow your app to run on older versions of Android if you are using API calls that aren't available on whatever the nook runs.  1.4 isn't a real version FYI.

http://developer.android.com/sdk/compatibility-library.html

Now you might run into bugs that exist in earlier versions that have been fixed in 3.2.  Those bugs might require you rework your features.